# Most Efficient way to test large number of strings against a large List<string>

Tags: c#, string, linq, performance

I've looked at a number of other similar questions, but the methods given seem too slow for what I am trying to accomplish, or are testing for partial matches, which I don't need and should be slower.

I have two large files filled with strings, I need to check each string in one list to see if it matches any of the strings in the second list. I don't need to check for partial matches, and everything should be properly escaped.

The second list (of strings to remove) contains 160,000 strings. I've loaded this into a `List<String>` and then was reading each line of the larger file and testing it using `List<String>.Any(line.contains)`.

Even with only a small part of the first list (40k strings), this is taking a long time, probably over 20 minutes on my fast development computer.

**Here's My Question**

Is there a more/What is the most efficient way of comparing a large list of strings individually against another larger list of strings, when no partial matches are needed.

Comment: sounds suspiciously like you are doing the work of a database?

Comment: No, its just a simple app for cleaning some CSVs. It wasn't supposed to take this long to make, and isn't going to be used very often.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Instead of using a `List<string>`, use a `HashSet<string>`.  It has O(1) lookups instead of O(n) like the list.  You should see orders of magnitude speedup if you make this change.

It may also give you slightly better performance to use [`HashSet.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx), rather than LINQ's `.Any()` extension method.

Comment: Wow, unbelievable improvement. The 40k string file too 20-30 minutes to compare. When testing I accidentally used larger nearly 1 million string list, and it took around 10 seconds. Plus I only had to change two lines to make it work.

Comment: "I accidentally the whole list".

Comment: Is "slightly better performance" referring to `O(1)` vs `O(N)`? Because 'slightly' is not the right term then. :)

Comment: @Rotsor:  I was assuming that `.Any()` is special cased for `HashSet`s, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @recursive, I don't think generic method can be special-cased, modulo some reflection tricks. Also, even special-cased `.Any()` can't work faster than `O(N)`.

Comment: @Rotsor, why not?  I'm not sure if it actually works that way, but I've attached an example of such an optimization.  http://pastebin.com/eWnmCnth

Comment: That's the reflection trick I was talking about (`as` is). As for complexity, that's not `Any` you have there. `Contains` can be fast, yes.

Comment: Ah, it's a misunderstanding then.  I've never considered `as` or `is` to be reflection.

Comment: @Rotsor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1342/discussion-between-recursive-and-rotsor)

Comment: @Rotsor: A lot of extension methods in Linq are special cased for at least some types.

Comment: @Rotsor: `as` has nothing to do with reflection. Reflection is accessing code *metadata* in runtime (like playing with `Type` object), and `as` is implemented as several MSIL instructions with no `GetType` calls.

Answer (score 26):

First off, I think your logic is just plain wrong. Passing a delegate to Contains to the Any method will do partial string matches and you have explicitly stated that you want only exact matches.

Leaving that aside, your performance problem is due to the nature of the list data structure; it was not designed to be efficiently searched via "Any".

The problem is that "Any" simply does a linear search, starting at the beginning of the list and blazing through it until it finds a match. If the list has 100K entries then every "miss" will do 100K string comparisons, and every "hit" will do on average 50K string comparisons.

That's terrible.

What you should do is convert the List into a HashSet of strings. The set takes up slightly more memory, but is *extremely* fast to search.

Another possible optimization is to sort one of the lists -- which is an O(n lg n) operation -- and then binary search the sorted list, which is an O(lg n) operation.

A third possible optimization is to sort both lists, and then write a sorted list comparer.  Obviously a sorted list comparer is much faster than an unsorted list comparer.  You keep an index into each list, and advance only the index that is pointing to the "smaller" item. That is, if the lists are

```
A, B, C, D, G, I
B, D, E, H, I
```

Then you start with indexes pointing at A and B. "A" is smaller, so you advance the first index to "B". Now they are the same; you have a match. Advance both of them. The first index is "C" and the second is "D".  "C" is smaller", so advance it...

---

More generally though, I think you are describing the problem at too low a level. I feel like you're asking a question about drills when you should be asking a question about holes. Maybe a drill isn't the right tool in the first place. Can you tell us *why* you are matching two big lists of strings? Perhaps there is an easier way to do what you want.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I really had no idea how to do it in the first place, the method I was using was the most common solution to the most similar scenario I could find. Realizing it wasn't sufficient, I came here to pose the right question.

Comment: also you could use radix sort to decrease the sorting order for the second and third approaches to O(n)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Union` and `Except` operators to get the differences and similarities between your two lists.

**Union:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx

**Except:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx

Each function returns a list containing the resulting data.

Comment: These should increase the readability of the code, but would not speed up the complexity as long as the containers are Lists.

Comment: @SethO: Can you explain your comment?  Why would it not speed up? What do the implementation details *of the sequence* have to do with the matter?

Comment: @Eric L: I'm saying that the choice data structure matters most for the OP's primary concern - speed. As you suggested in your reply post, changing the underlying container (e.g., List to Hashset) gives the efficiency the OP seeks. List1.Except(List2) still suffers from linear complexity restrictions, no?

Comment: @SethO: Your claim is that list1.Except(list2) is O(n^2)? On what do you base that conclusion?

Comment: @Eric L: It was tepid claim, I admit (which is why I sought input in my last comment). But, to your specific question, I got my information on Except() from MSDN and its signature (IEnumerable<T>) and (drumroll, please) made assumptions on implementation. Is Except()'s implementation optimized to provide O(n)?

Comment: @SethO: The implementation of Except is: `Set<T> set = new Set<T>(comparer);
foreach (T element in second) set.Add(element);
foreach (T element in first) if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;` -- so, provided that set.Add is O(1) in time and space, and the sequences are of size m and n, then the algorithm is O(m+n) in time and O(n) in space.

Comment: @Eric L: Thank you for the clear explanation. In retrospect, I should have looked at the library in ILSpy/Reflector as soon as I had questions about implementation. However, I enjoyed our conversation. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why no one has mentioned [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) yet. This is a quite efficient and very straightforward function to use here.

Answer (score 2):

You could insert each element of the first list into a `HashSet<string>`, and then test each element of the second for presence in the set. That only hits each item once, and the insertion and testing should be O(1) (unless your dataset is pathological for some reason.)

Answer (score -1):

The strings are known up front, so a sorted vector will be faster than a hash map. Hash the strings from the smaller file with a string-friendly hash such as [FNV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) and put them into a

```
vector<pair<int, string> >
```

Define functions to make it sortable and comparable on the hash, then `sort` the vector.

```
bool operator < (pair<int, string> const&, pair<int, string> const&) { ... }
bool operator < (pair<int, string> const&, int) { ... }
bool operator < (int, pair<int, string> const&) { ... }
```

Now read each string from the larger file, hash it and search the vector with `equal_range`. Compare the full strings only where the hashes match. (Note: extra magic may be required to search by hash instead of using a dummy `pair<int, string>`.)

If a longer delay before output begins is acceptable and sufficient space is available, it may be faster to load both files into sorted vectors, find the matching hashes with [`set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) and compare their full strings. I'll leave the details as an exercise for the reader (:-). Remember that there could be hash collisions on both sides.